# returning an object from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to add a instance inside a function in javscript where i have observed the following behavior

```
function Calculator () {
    this.mm = 66;
    return 2 ;
}

var calculator = new Calculator();
console.log('  --> '+calculator.mm);   <<< gives output of 66
```

But the below code

```
function Calculator () {
    this.mm = 66;
    return {} ;
}

var calculator = new Calculator();
console.log('  --> '+calculator.mm);   <<< gives me undefined
```

I just want to know what different does returning an object from a primitive datatype make to a function . In other words why am i getting undefined here and not 66.

Comment: Why are you returning from that pattern?

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2522-providing-a-return-value-in-a-javascript-constructor.htm

Comment: You are returning an empty object which doesn't have a property of mm. Return 'this' instead.

Answer (score -2):

you should return the variable mm in the second one.
Like  return mm;
That should solve your problem.
Since you are not returning anything in the second one, that is why it is coming back as undefined.

Comment: function Calculator () {
         this.mm = 66;
         return {k:'aaa'} ;
    }   even this gives me undefined while trying to access 'mm'

Comment: why are you doing that? Just do return mm; - That's all you need to do.